# Не получается отобразить SVG файл через intent

Tags: android

Помогите, пожалуйста, понять, почему не происходит отрисовка SVG файла при передаче его из одной активности в другую. Библиотеку `svgAndroid2.12Dec2011.jar` подключил, файл в SVG формате поместил в raw.

Из:

```
// нажатие на элемент
    expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this,
                    SecondActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            if (groups[0] != null && items_groups_one[0] != null && id == 0)
                intent.putExtra(SecondActivity.PICTURE,
                        png_items_groups_one[0]);
            startActivity(intent);

            return false;
        }

    });
```

В:

```
public class SecondActivity extends FirstActivity implements OnClickListener {
public static final String PICTURE = "picture";

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

    ImageView image = new ImageView(this);

    image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.aboutImage);
    image.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
    image.setImageDrawable(drawable);

}

Intent intent = getIntent();
// Получаем данные от деятельности FirstActivity и парсим в SVG
SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(),
        intent.getIntExtra(PICTURE, png_items_groups_one[0]));
Drawable drawable = svg.createPictureDrawable();
```

Лог пишет:

```
09-26 09:56:14.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1736): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-26 09:56:14.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1736): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{ua.fundator.i/ua.fundator.i.SecondActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-26 09:56:14.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2137)
09-26 09:56:14.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
09-26 09:56:14.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-26 09:56:14.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
09-26 09:56:14.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-26 09:56:14.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-26 09:56:14.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-26 09:56:14.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-26 09:56:14.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-26 09:56:14.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-26 09:56:14.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-26 09:56:14.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-26 09:56:14.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1736): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-26 09:56:14.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:89)
09-26 09:56:14.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getResources(ContextThemeWrapper.java:78)
09-26 09:56:14.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at ua.fundator.i.SecondActivity.<init>(SecondActivity.java:33)
09-26 09:56:14.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
09-26 09:56:14.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1130)
09-26 09:56:14.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1061)
09-26 09:56:14.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2128)
09-26 09:56:14.441: E/AndroidRuntime(1736):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: что содержится в 28 строке SecondActivity?

Comment: Извините. Пришлось изменить код SecondActivity потому, что SVGParser начинает "жить" (появляется подсветка кода только за границами метода
onCreate.
Лог тоже переписал.
Посмотрите, пожалуйста, ещё раз.

Comment: Инициализация переменной
   
 int imageId_one = intent.getIntExtra(PICTURE, png_items_groups_one[0]);
SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), imageId_one);
 Drawable drawable = svg.createPictureDrawable();
 

то же ничего не дала. Лог тот же.

Comment: хорошо, теперь что в 33 строке SecondActivity?

Comment: 33 строка: // Получаем данные от деятельности FirstActivity и парсим в SVG
34 строка: SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), imageId_one);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Там же ясно написано `NullPointerException` - берите в руки отладчик, ставьте брекпойнт на первый оператор `SecondActivity.onCreate()` и вперед. Через 5 минут вы все и сами найдете.

Comment: Если бы всё было так просто, разве искал бы я помощи на форуме? Ни Debug ни FindBugs вообще ничего не пишут! Не знаю, может, это какой-то глюк моего эклипса...

Comment: Всё! Разобрался - библиотека svgAndroid2.12Dec2011.jar не "катит".